# LED REACT TO MUSIC

Tags: led-strip

I want to ask if anyone can tell me what transistor and resistor I need to use for 5v led RGB lights ( i need them in green or blue only).

Here is a link to the video I'm taking info from:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WsblfCXvu-Y

P.S. I have no idea how to work electrics or use tools but I want to try and make it work, thank you very much :)

Comment: Please don't use all-caps in your title.

Comment: [Not the best, but probably clearer than some fuzzy video.](https://www.instructables.com/id/LED-strip-Synced-MUSIC/)

Comment: Search on "LED color organ".

Answer (score 1):

There is a computer virus on the link to the microphone used.
A microphone will not work anyway unless it feeds a preamp which is not in the video.

The video uses a 12V LED strip that has current-limiting resistors to prevent the LEDs from instantly burning out. Each color in each of your LEDs needs its own current-limiting resistor calculated so that the current is not too high for the LED.